# Is Cherie (Frenchie's girlfriend?) in "The Boys" blind?

Tags: character, the-boys

After they capture Translucent and Billy Butcher takes Hughie to Frenchie's place, season 1, early in episode 2,  Frenchie's girlfriend Cherie feels Hughie's face, but she wears sunglasses and takes them off when she opens the door, so it was an odd scene.

When I first saw that, with the touching and the way she grabs the door on her way back in, it appears she's blind, but highly functioning.  Her eyes also have a strange tint to them.

But there's no indication that she's blind in later scenes, which are relatively few, so I just wanted to confirm, she's supposed to be high-functioning blind or is that a wrong assumption?

The show was very well put together, so I don't think they'd put the face touching scene in there for no reason.

Comment: Great question!  I got the sense that she could see but was feeling his face because he is "pretty".  Not sure if Frenchy and Cherie are traffickers and she was seeing what price he would fetch.  She was pretty quickly able to prepare an explosive getway later in the season so I would guess she is not blind

Answer (score 6):

I don't know that these are sufficient examples but I feel that a case can be made that she is not blind.

As I mentioned in a comment, in Episode 3 - she single-handledly disposes of a location to throw off the pursuit by some Supes.

In Episode 4, she brings some knockout gas grenades to Frenchie and shows him how it works and jokingly threatens him with them should their relationship go sour.

In neither instance did her performance indicate lack of sight or compensating for it.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure Frenchie asks Huey something like "you're working with this guy (meaning Butcher) and you still have your eyes?". To which Butcher says "you've still got yours".  That leaves only Cherie's missing eyeballs that they could be alluding to.

I think though I dont know, that her eyes are somehow synthetic, and its possible she "turns them off" or something sometimes.

Comment: There is the possibility that someone else they have worked with in the past has lost their eyes, not necessarily Cherie

Comment: yeah didn't mean to say that proves anything, it just kind of suggests to me that they're talking about Cherie given everything we know

Comment: I see you are new to the community and let me say, welcome!  This is an awesome site and you will find great peers with amazing backgrounds and interests in the great art that is cinema and television.  In the specific case of this series, it is an adaptation of a particularly graphic novel so it's possible to say for example things that Billy Butcher may have done in the original publication, such as keep a man-eating dog, named Terror who is infused with V.  I haven't seen any references to cybernetic/synthetic eyes in either series, though